# How to store BigDecimal type data in Elastic Search and sort by that value?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do I store BigDecimal type data in Elastic Search and sort by that value?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I am afraid it is [not supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html). The closest you will get is `double`.

## To test

In this quick test, I create 4 documents (that goes from bigger to smaller sorted on the `_id`)

```
POST /_bulk/
{"index":{"_index":"72344005","_id":"2"}}
{"data":123456789.123456789}
{"index":{"_index":"72344005","_id":"3"}}
{"data":-123456789.123456789}
{"index":{"_index":"72344005","_id":"1"}}
{"data":223456789.123456789}
{"index":{"_index":"72344005","_id":"0"}}
{"data":223456789.123456889}

GET /72344005/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "data": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The query give back documents sort like so `1, 0, 2, 3`. Supporting the claim that we loose some precision. during the indexation.

Comment: 我需要将长度超过32的数字存入elastic search 并排序,long 和 double都不符合

Comment: Could you speak in English please? This is the English stack overflow this will make it easier for everyone to follow along

Comment: sorry,I need to put more numbers than the maximum value of Long into ES and sort them

Comment: There are no viable solution as far as I know. Do you need the full range of BigDecimal ? it is possible to create another field that would store a number with a smaller range ?

Comment: For example, if I want to compare 500000000000000000000000000 and 600000000000000000000000000, what do I do

Comment: I would reduce the dimensions between the 2, before ingesting the doc. In this case because you only have 2 doc. I would say one is 5 the other is 6.

Comment: The issue is that in your dataset, if you have a doc with 500000000000000000000000001 things are going to be even more complicated

Comment: Not only have 500000000000000000000000001 and 500000000000000000000000002

Comment: Well, this is my only idea... I am not sure ow to deal with it... you might have to get creative.